# iOS 6 & iOS 7 Status Bar

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios6

There are multiple questions about "switching from iOS 6 Status Bar to iOS 7", but I would like to ask the opposite.

**My question is:** How can I make iOS 6 screen frame slip under the status bar? I tried to move the `self.window.frame` and `self.window.bounds` in App Delegate, it is okay to shift up under the status bar, but the bottom will leave a 20 ~ 40px black line.

Here is the codes:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6 && [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7) {
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    self.window.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0, -20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height + 40);
    self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, -40, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height + 80);
}
```

I tried many values, but none fits my needs. What did I miss? I think I'm close.

Here is the mock screenshot I want to achieve ( I know the signal status of iOS 6 is not like this. Just to show the idea )

[image: iOS 6 & 7 Difference]

Note: only needs to support iOS 6+

Answer (score 0):

My final solution is to remove the codes in App Delegate, and add `IBOutlet` to the header image of each page.

Then, in the method `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7")) {
    [iv_header setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
}
```

where the if-case is defined as:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```